# robot_localization EKF internal motion model

Tags: navigation, odometry, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I was not able to find this information in the documentation of the [`robot_localization` package](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) nor its source code, does anybody know what the "internal motion model" is that is used in the`ekf_robot_localization` node?

Edit: In the corresponding [paper](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=robot_localization_ias13_revised.pdf), the authors state that they use a "standard 3D kinematic model derived from Newtonian mechanics", but I guess this model is derived from the kinematics of the test platform they used for the experiments.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221837/robot_localization-ekf-internal-motion-model/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a generic omnidirectional motion model which isn't all that complicated, but it's a bit much to write out here. In [this](http://perso.uclouvain.be/georges.bastin/paper37.pdf) paper, it corresponds to the robot type (3,0), but the model in *robot_localization* is in 3D. Each variable has a nonlinear transition function, and we encode those transition functions as a matrix. So, for example, the transition function for x is `x_new = x_old + vx * t + 0.5 * a * t^2,` but `v` and `a` are given in the body frame of the robot, so we have to apply 3D rotations to them. The orientations have similar logic. Velocities (for x) are just `vx_new = vx_old + at`. Each row in the matrix is a transition function. We then derive the Jacobian analytically.

Naturally, this won't necessarily match ever robot perfectly, but in practice, it works pretty well for a broad range of robots. You an always increase the `process_noise_covariance` matrix values if the model doesn't match your robot well.

If you want to take a look, check out the [predict](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/indigo-devel/src/ekf.cpp#L209) function.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2015-12-04**:
thanks Tom and great work by the way! :-)

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-12-04**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [fastestindian](https://answers.ros.org/users/29273/fastestindian/) on 2017-08-22**:
Hi Tom,

We want to use robot_localization to localise a non-holonomic platform, aka ackermann. I was wondering if the 3D motion model in the EKF/UKF nodes would cover these motion constraints, and if so, is there a chance it could fail for an ackermann platform? Your advise is appreciated!

**Comment by [kgandhi24](https://answers.ros.org/users/31957/kgandhi24/) on 2017-09-19**:
Hey Tom,
If sensor data ( encoder and IMU ) has been used in prediction step and which data are you using in correction step?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-09-19**:
The prediction step is handled entirely by the motion model. IMU and encoder data is used in correction.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-09-19**:
@fastestindian The motion model isn't really conducive to Ackermann platforms (in 2D mode, it's really just a unicycle model), but it depends on the data you feed it. If you are feeding it pose data from some other Ackerman model, then the prediction step will be a bit off, but will get corrected.

**Comment by [plafer](https://answers.ros.org/users/60526/plafer/) on 2020-10-15**:
I looked everywhere for this information, and I feel like it really should be included in the documentation of the package!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-10-16**:
Yeeaaaah, it probably should, I agree. Feel free to file a ticket, but I can't promise anything soon, sorry. :(

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2023-05-05**:
Great explanation, Tom. Thank you for your great work!